# Do I need Paypal Pro to accept credit cards on my ecommerce store?

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I've recently tested sandbox on paypal. But I have to have Paypal Pro enabled to complete my transaction. According to information provided to paypal, the standard account should accept credit card.
(https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products)
So do I need to purchase Paypal pro to accept credit card or was this only required in sandbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not. The basic, free account is enough. The Pro accounts simply come with premium features, like being able to process transactions without your customers needing to leave your website. The basic account redirects them to Paypal long enough to complete the checkout before redirecting back to your site.